# What is the difference between Thread Object and Worker Object (php pthreads)

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

The only explanation that I've found so far is here: http://pthreads.org

But what does that mean in terms of code? When should I use Worker(s) and where should I use Threads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are both Threads, but, a Thread is intended to execute one task ( that defined in it's run method ) and then exit. A Worker is intended to wait for tasks, in the form of Stackable derived objects, implementing their own run methods and execute them from a stack in the order they are inserted.

In this way, the Worker allows you to reuse a context, they provide a means of efficiency quite difficult to program in userland, but nothing like impossible.

Comment: Wouldn't it be slow to instantiate everytime a new Stackable instead of adding a callback (in array/string form)? e.g. `$stack[] = ["ExClass", "method"];` and do in one thread: `while (true) { if (count($stack)) ${'callback'.!($callback = $stack->shift())}(); else $this->wait(); }`